# How can I display social media icons in a horizontal line instead of vertical row

Tags: html, css

I have a webstore on Shopify. On the product page, under the product description, I have social media icons displayed down in a row. How can I adjust them to show side by side one another as one line horizontally?

Here is a link to a product page: 
http://www.vapestore.co/collections/featured-products/products/innokin-itaste-svd

Here is some CSS code:

```
.icon-social { display:block; float:left; }
.icon-social { margin-right:5px; margin-bottom: 5px; }
.icon-social { text-indent:-9999px; width:32px; height:32px; opacity:0.3; filter: alpha(opacity = 30); background: url({{ 'social-icons-light-bg.png' | asset_url }}) no-repeat; }
.icon-social:hover { opacity:0.6; filter: alpha(opacity = 60); }
.icon-social.twitter { background-position: 0 0; }
.icon-social.facebook { background-position: -50px 0; }
.icon-social.youtube { background-position: -100px 0; }
.icon-social.atom { background-position: -150px 0; }
.icon-social.instagram { background-position: -200px 0; }
.icon-social.pinterest { background-position: -250px 0; }
.icon-social.vimeo { background-position: -300px 0; }
.icon-social.tumblr { background-position: -350px 0; }
.icon-social.google { background-position: -400px 0; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#social div {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
```

Result:

[image]

You could also sub in display:inline-block for float:left and the result is essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think what what would be easyest is to make all the icons display Inline Block?

```
.icon-social { display:inline-block; float:left; }
```

This should work :)

Comment: You don't need both float:left and display:inline-block, as the results are essentially the same, at least in this context.